# Различия в выполнении скрипта из командной строки и в качестве модуля Апач

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Следующая команда выполняется успешно

```
php /var/www/html/mysqlconnect.php
```

Тот же скрипт при обращении к WEB серверу на Apache 2.2.x (PHP 5.3 Lib64) говорит о невозможности подключения через сокет MySQL. PHP в Апач работает, так как `phpinfo()` выводит необходимую информацию.

Из командной строки выполняется гарантировано, так как выводится содержание таблиц. Права на сокет проверял - всё в норме. Почему так?

Comment: "Всё в норме" для какого пользователя?

Comment: Какая именно ошибка выдается?

Comment: >"Всё в норме" для какого пользователя? 

Да дошло до того, что добавил пользователя апач в группу мускула, запускал апач от имени пользователя мускул, сокет ложил в общедоступный каталог
Кроме того, выполняю этот скрипт с командной строки от имени апач-пользователя и таблица выводится

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (13) in

Comment: Платформа:
Linux server 3.1.0-7.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 21:10:48 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

PHP Version 5.3.10

Apache 2.0 Handler

Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora)

Comment: Итак, проблема перешла в другую плоскость
Поменяв runlevel5 на runlevel3, всё заработало само собой
Файервол iptables отключен и на 3, и на 5
Возможно, это вопрос какой-то службы Fedora Core 16?

Comment: Вы PHP-скриптик запускаете при старте ОС, видимо? Когда MySQL-сервер ещё не запущен?